# Dealing with textbox within the Gridview control in asp.net?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview

I am developing a comment section page and I used textboxes,button, and a gridview control to insert comments and display them respectively. I have a textbox outside from the gridview for adding comments, meanwhile I also have another textbox within the gridview to add replies to each comments. I displayed all the comments and replies within the gridview control respectively. I noticed that if I enter comments from the textbox which is located outside the gridview using this syntax below

```
string comment = Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox2.Text.Replace("'", "''"));
comment = Server.HtmlEncode(comment.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>"));

connection.Open();
string sql = "INSERT INTO [ComTab]([Name],[Comments]) Values('" + commentor + "','" + comment + "')";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Dispose();
connection.Close();
```

I can save this line ***<br/><br/>*** along with my comments into my database if you are making a multi-paragraph comments. So no questions about it, thats what I want.
Now in contrary, if I enter a reply into the textbox which is located inside the gridview using the following codes below

```
Button btn2 = (Button)sender;
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)btn2.NamingContainer;
TextBox gridtxt2 = row.FindControl("TextBox4") as TextBox;

string reply = Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox3.Text.Replace("'", "''"));
reply = Server.HtmlEncode(reply.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>"));

connection.Open();
string sql = "INSERT INTO [RepTab]([Name],[Replies]) Values('" + commentor + "','" + reply + "')";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Dispose();
connection.Close();
```

I can't save this line anymore ***<br/><br/>*** along with my replies into my database which is why if the user inputs a multi-paragraph reply, it won't display multi-paragraph reply but instead it is compressed into one long paragraph. So how do I able to save this line ***<br/><br/>*** along with my replies into my database? Any suggestions? Thanks...

Comment: Sql injection detected :) I do hope someone will add reply '); drop table users;--

Comment: What do you suggest? What do you mean?

Comment: What Ondrej is saying is, if you use string concatenation to create a SQL string, that you send to the database, you are vulnerable to someone adding an additional SQL command to the one you are trying to execute. This means that someone could drop your database, given the permissions didn't stop him. A better way would be to use SQL parameters in your query, which give some protection against SQL injection. So you would call it like sql = "insert into x(a,b) values(@paramA, @paramB)". Then below you would call cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramA", textbox1.Value) etc. Hope that clears it.

Comment: did you want to remove "<br/>" from your html reply??

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar No. I dont want to remove this line &lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt; which is equal to new line or <br/> when entering a reply so that I can display the reply in a correct format if the user enters multi-paragraph reply.

Comment: @AndrejKikelj I understand what you're saying. Im not trying to save <br/> into the database but instead of this &lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt; which is missing if you enter your reply in the textbox which is located inside the gridview control.

Comment: Why are you encoding the <br />? Also, is your textbox marked as multiline?

Comment: @AndrejKikelj I'm encoding this line &lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt; which is equal to <br/> so that I can display replies with multi-paragraph content.Of course I set my textbox to multiline. Can you please analyze my thread again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to replace \n with `<br/>` or encode it. You can save \r\n, and print it back out and the textbox will display the new line. If you are writing out the text directly into the response without a control though, you need to make sure that someone isn't injecting javascript into your database, which would be able to do some nasty stuff when loaded out.

Edit - final solution:

Try setting the text property of the column in your grid that is rendering the response as

```
Text='<%#  Eval("reply").ToString().Replace("\n", "<br />") %>'
```

and don't replace the \n when you save to db. Also, be sure you output JS clean code to prevent misuse.

Comment: That is why I'm wondering why I can display multi-paragraph comments meanwhile cannot display reply with multi-paragraph content when they are just using the same codes. Therefore the other one cannot save this line &lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt; into my database.

Comment: I can't save this line anymore &lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt; along with my replies into my database which is why if the user inputs a multi-paragraph reply, it won't display multi-paragraph reply but instead it is compressed into one long paragraph. So how do I able to save this line &lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt; along with my replies into my database? Any suggestions? Thanks...

Comment: Which control do you use to display the comments, and which one to display the reply?

Comment: I used nested gridview to display both

Comment: Can you try setting the text property of the column in your grid that is rendering the response as 
    Text='<%# Eval("reply").ToString().Replace("\n", "<br />") %>'
and don't replace the \n when you save to db.

Comment: When you say don't replace \n with <br/> when saving to database would that be something like this now? reply = Server.HtmlEncode(reply.Replace("\r", "<br/>"));

Comment: Thanks this is just what I've missed in childgridview where replies being displayed <p><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Replies").ToString().Replace("\n", "<br />")  %> </p>. I wonder why it wont save &lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt; when you're entering from the textbox which is inside the gridview unlike entering from the textbox which is outside the gridview maybe that's their limitation but its OK atleast I can display now the correct format...Thanks again